# Did Padme's death have something to do with Anakin's force choke?

Tags: star-wars, revenge-of-the-sith, padme

They said that she lost the will to live, but was there other complications when she gave birth and she just didn't have the will to fight it? And if so, is it possible that Anikan's force choke caused it (physically, obviously it hurt her mentally)? Or did she just decide two children are not reason enough to live and just died of grief?